# `mypy` error on using Protocol with dataclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-dataclasses

I have the following code where I'm defining dummy dummy class with function and variable template. I'm trying to type-hint this with `Protocol`.
I get the following error on analyzing with `mypy`:

```
$mypy --ignore-missing-imports --no-strict-optional --no-implicit-optional --explicit-package-bases --namespace-packages tmp.py 
tmp.py:4: error: Only concrete class can be given where "Type[Person]" is expected
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I'm new to this. Can someone please help me with this?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Apr 12 14:12:27 2023

@author: alankar
"""
import numpy as np
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Protocol, Optional, Union

@dataclass
class dm_halo(Protocol):
    r0: Optional[float] = None
    UNIT_LENGTH: Optional[float] = None
    
@dataclass
class unmodified_field(Protocol):
    Halo: Optional["dm_halo"] = None
    rCGM: Optional[float] = None
    metallicity: Optional[np.ndarray] = None
    UNIT_LENGTH: Optional[float] = None
    
    def ProfileGen(self, radius: Union[float, int, list[float], list[int], np.ndarray]):
        pass
    
@dataclass
class modified_field(Protocol):    
    ionization: Optional[float] = None
    redshift: Optional[float] = None
    unmodfied: Optional["unmodified_field"] = None
    UNIT_LENGTH: Optional[float] = None
    TempDist: Optional[np.ndarray] = None
    Tcut: Optional[np.ndarray] = None
    prs_hot: Optional[np.ndarray] = None
    prs_warm: Optional[np.ndarray] = None
    nhot_local: Optional[np.ndarray] = None
    sigH: Optional[float] = None
    sigW: Optional[float] = None
    TmedVW: Optional[float] = None
    TmedVH: Optional[float] = None
    nHhot_local: Optional[np.ndarray] = None
    nHwarm_local: Optional[np.ndarray] = None
    fvw: Optional[np.ndarray] = None
    
    def ProfileGen(self, radius: Union[float, int, list[float], list[int], np.ndarray]):
        pass
```

EDIT:
Apologies! I was trying a simpler case to get a similar issue. Here is the error specific to this code:

```
$ mypy --ignore-missing-imports --no-strict-optional --no-implicit-optional --explicit-package-bases --namespace-packages ./tmp.py 
tmp.py:5: error: Only concrete class can be given where "Type[dm_halo]" is expected
tmp.py:10: error: Only concrete class can be given where "Type[unmodified_field]" is expected
tmp.py:20: error: Only concrete class can be given where "Type[modified_field]" is expected
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Here is a simpler code that produces similar error:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Protocol

@dataclass
class Person(Protocol):
    name: str
    age: int

    def greet(self) -> str:
        pass

    def celebrate_birthday(self) -> None:
        pass

@dataclass
class Employee:
    name: str
    age: int
    position: str

    def greet(self) -> str:
        return f"Hello, my name is {self.name} and I'm a {self.position}."

    def celebrate_birthday(self) -> None:
        self.age += 1
```

Error:

```
$ mypy --ignore-missing-imports --no-strict-optional --no-implicit-optional --explicit-package-bases --namespace-packages ./tmp.py 
tmp.py:4: error: Only concrete class can be given where "Type[Person]" is expected
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

EDIT:
I'm using `mypy 0.942`
I checked with the latest `mypy 1.2.0` and the error is gone. I don't know what is the difference between the two versions.

Comment: The error you are showing is not from the code you have in the question. The code in the question does not give any errors

Comment: Your code doesn't produce the stated lint error. That said, what do you think `Protocol` is? It doesn't make much sense to mix it with dataclasses in this way. You presumably want to create dataclasses that _implement_ one or more separate protocols, or drop the protocols altogether

Comment: Also, why `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-`. This isn't supposed to Python 2, is it?

Comment: @Brian61354270 Spyder auto-generated this.

Comment: I will also say that you are using `Protocol` in an unexpected way. Can you explain what you were trying to achieve with `Protocol` here?

Comment: Could you please reduce your code to a [mre]? The provided code [still doesn't produce those lint errors](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=ignore-missing-imports%2Cno-implicit-optional%2Cno-strict-optional&gist=c2efb8caf8f76022d3a2facc02fd323e).

Comment: Yeah, seriously. Note, line 5, where the first error is purportedly coming from, is inside the docstring `@author: alankar` so ....

Comment: After further testing, it appears that mypy emits those lints for version 0.971 and below, but not 0.981+. That said, the fact that recent versions of mypy _aren't_ emitting those lints may be a regression (and worth a bug report). Protocols _cannot be instantiated_, so it seems reasonable that decoratoring one with `dataclass` should be an error.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I wanted to create a template of member functions and variables of these large and complicated classes, objects of which are passed later to objects of other classes and functions. Since I had a lot of member variables, I wanted to use dataclass.

Comment: @curious What do you mean by "template"? In any case, not sure *why* you thought `dataclass` would matter, again, it doesn't really make sense to use it with a `Protocol`, what exactly is the `dataclass` helping you with there?

Comment: @Brian61354270 I don't think that's necessarily true, it could signify that your Protocol expects it to have various dataclass members that would get added. So if I do it, for example, mypy will complain `"Bar" is missing following "Foo" protocol members: __dataclass_fields__, __match_args__` where `Foo` is decorated with `dataclass` and just has an `x: int` and `Bar` isn't decorated with `dataclass` and also just has `x: int`, but I agree, this would be weird

Comment: Creating a Protocol dataclass is really next level... Seriously though, I would suggest you read [PEP 544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/) to understand what Protocols are for. What they are decidedly _not_ for is being instantiated. So unless you _actually_ need structural rather than nominal subtyping, you will probably be better off defining a normal (possibly abstract) base class.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga By template I meant that I will have a class that will list down the attributes and functions of many similar types of long and complicated classes. So that later when objects of these classes are used in other functions or classes as arguments, their typing can simply be this generic template class and there is no need to import the respective classes. The imports could then only be done wherever these objects are actually instantiated and passed as arguments to other functions.

Comment: I wanted to use `dataclass` as I had a long list of variables in the template and `dataclass` provides a default initialization.

Comment: @curious **Protocols are not meant to be instantiated**. There is no point in providing default initialization. You only should add `dataclass` to a protocol if you mean that the protocol should only apply to *other* classes that have applied that decorator (or rather, that have the same structural result).

Comment: Terminology note, the term you want is "I want to use Protocol for *structural typing*"

Comment: Also this error is gone and shows success on using `mypy 1.2.0` rather than `mypy 0.942`.

Comment: yes, but almost *certainly* you don't want to be using `dataclass` here

Comment: I guess even if I get rid of the `@dataclass` and have the variables as class variables, the functionality that I want to achieve is good to go.
@juanpa.arrivillaga thanks a lot for taking the time to explain this. I'm a newbie.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Just to be very precise, Protocols are not just _not meant_ to be, they **can not** be instantiated. This is just a misuse of protocols in place where a simple (abstract) base class class would do exactly what OP wants to accomplish.